# SSRS executing a Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a Report in SSRS VS2008 that needs to run a Stord Procedure from Oracle.  In the past I have run functions from Oracle that return tables in order to display the data.  As well as straight forward SELECT statements

For example:

```
select * from table(MyFunction(:parm1, :parm2))
select * from MyTable
```

I have not run a Stored Procedure from Oracle in SSRS and I am wondering....

How do I define the Query in the DataSet to return the results?

Comment: Are you directly accessing Oracle, or is it via a Linked Server instance?

Comment: It is directly accessing Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stored procedure with an output parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR, and place the results of the query in the output cursor within the procedure - like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_myproc(L_CURSOR out SYS_REFCURSOR) 
is
   BEGIN
     OPEN L_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT * FROM mytable;
   END;
```

Then create the dataset in your report -  on the Query tab, set the Command type to StoredProcedure, and the Query string to the name of the procedure, eg. pr_myproc. If you check the fields tab, these should match the expected structure of the cursor, ie. the query output.