# How do I specify an Oracle cursor in the rdl to fetch the records in the report

Tags: .net, oracle

I am using a procedure that uses a cursor as an out parameter to fetch the records. But the problem is I don't know how to specify the parameters in rdl(xml).

Comment: [This article](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3524781/Tap-into-Oracle-Databases-with-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services.htm) didn't cover RDL format details but may be useful for getting example of correct definition.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025588/ssrs-executing-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle)