# can i set up an SSRS report where users input parameters to a table

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have an oracle query that uses a created table as part of the code.  Every time I need to run a report I delete current data and import the new data I receive. This is one column of id's.  I need to create a report on SSRS in which the user can input this data into said table as a parameter.  I have designed a simple report that they can enter some of the id's into a parameter, but there may be times when they need to enter in a few thousand id's, and the report already runs long. Here is what the SSRS code currently says:

```
select distinct n.id, n.notes
from notes n
join (
     select max(seq_num) as seqnum, id from notes group by id) maxresults
on n.id = maxresults.ID   
where  n.seq_num = maxresults.seqnum
and n.id in (@MyParam)
```

Is there a way to have MyParam insert data into a table I would join called My_ID, joining  as Join My_Id id on n.id = id.id

I do not have permissions to create functions or procedures in the database.

Thank you

Comment: The only way to get SSRS to write back is to get it to call a store procedure as it' ssource, and in that stored procedure, insert the data. You can't run an insert statement from SSRS.

Comment: If I call a stored procedure from the report, can the user input the data into a parameter box that would insert it into the table?

Comment: Yes. You define a parameter in the report and you pass that parameter into the stored procedure and it can do what it likes with it (including insert into a table). I've had this working in SQL Server. My colleague has done it in Oracle. Only tricky thing would be passing a huge list of id's in. It's not very practical for those purposes.

Comment: Your real challenge here is getting a friendly user interface to be able to upload big lists of id's. Where do these id's come from? are they manually selected? From another list?

Comment: The list is id's that representatives have worked and they need to know that last notes in the database for those id's. At this point an Excel spreadsheet is sent to me and I import the id's into a table and run the query. (Basically, for this list of id's I would like to know the notes in the database). However, users would like the ability to run the report themselves via SSRS. Its not a list by dates that I could pull out just with the query, or by any other column attribute. So the interface is limited to what SSRS allows. Do you have an example of a stored procedure I could adapt?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an example of an oracle stored procedure but this question does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025588/ssrs-executing-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle. However if I understand correctly your issue is performance? Is that correct? I don't know that loading the id's into the database will actually improve performance (it could). You might be better off first trying to optimise the existing query. First stop: `DISTINCT`

Comment: Looking at your query further: are you sure you need distinct? removing this might speed it up a lot. Using windowing functions might speed it up and adding indexes might also speed it up

Answer (score 0):

You may try the trick with `MATERIALIZE` hint which normally forces Oracle to create a temporary table :

```
WITH cte1 AS
 ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ 1 as id FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2 DUAL
 )
 SELECT a.* 
 FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN cte1 b ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: a1ex07, how would I populate that view from user input when they run the report?

Comment: One way is to convert comma-separated list  (code taken from http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/184666/ ) : `with test as 
     select '421907802490,421907672085,421911460415,421905464170,421907802292' col from dual)
    select regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) result
    from test
    connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^,]+')) + 1;`

Comment: Actually the data is in a column in an Excel spreadsheet, and user would have to convert to csv. before entering into the report. I got the report to work just copying from excel, but only does a few id's at a time and runs very long.  Since they have need for a couple thousand at times, I need a better solution.

Comment: Can you use something like this to get direct access to the excel file (user could supply file name to read perhaps) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145389/is-there-an-equivalent-to-openrowset-in-oracle